# ElasticSearch : node does not have the data role but has shard data

Tags: elasticsearch

I setup elasticsearch cluster and I did not explicitly setup the role (node.roles:). Now ,I have gone back and edit one of the node config and assign to master (**node.roles:[master]**.

However, when I restart I get the error:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: node does not have the data role but has shard data: [/opt/elasticsearch/data/nodes**

How can I set the role explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a node gets the master and data role. So if you have started it already, it should already contain some data, and thus, cannot be transformed to a master node unless you first move all the data it contains on another node.

You first need to [decommission the node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/modules-cluster.html#cluster-shard-allocation-filtering) by running this command (use the right IP address for your node) in order to move all the data it contains on other data nodes:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "10.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

When the node doesn't contain any data anymore, you can shut it down, change `node.roles` to `master` and restart it.

Comment: Thanks.. but I get master_not_discovered_exception. I only have one node in the cluster

Comment: if you have a single master node in your cluster, I don't understand where you want to store the data...

Comment: thanks for help. Initially, I have 3 nodes that I did not assign roles. now I want to go back and assigned roles (2 master and 1 data). So, I stop all server and was just working on one node.. I guess I need to keep them up

Comment: You should just restart from scratch and properly configure all nodes before starting them

Comment: Thanks.. It seem this line  in the yaml is causing issue -- node.roles: [ master ]. Do I need to add it or will the "cluster.initial_master_nodes" value be enough

Comment: I believe if you are using a single node set (or even a single node, although I am not sure about this one), you will want to have both master and data assigned to node.roles aka `node.roles: ['master', 'data']` since otherwise it doesn't have any data nodes to put the data in.